# Select substring after occurence of words

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string `s`:

```
s = "this is a test <#1> that can be a very good test (#2) to look at [#3] test [#4], but also computer <#4> and test"
```

As you can see, it is a regular sentence that contains brackets of the form `<...>, (...)` or `[..]` with substrings between the brackets.

I want to extract the substrings within the brackets assuming that the bracket come *after* either the word `test` or `computer`. In other words, I want the following output:

```
[["test", "#1"], ["test", "#2"], ["test", "#4"], ["computer", "#4"]]
```

So far this is what I have: I can use a regular expression to locate the brackets, e.g.

```
import re
re.findall(re.compile("<.*?>"), s)
```

But now I need to generalize this to look for `[..]`, `(..)` as well *and* only in cases where the bracket comes after the word `test` or `computer`. Is it possible to achieve this with a regex?

Comment: there is neither `test` nor `computer` before `#3`.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I corrected this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(test|computer)\s[\[\(<](.*?)[\]\)>]
```

So, the code will be:

```
import re
pattern = r'(test|computer)\s[\[\(<](.*?)[\]\)>]'
print(re.findall(re.compile(p), s))
```

Output:

[('test', '#1'), ('test', '#2'), ('test', '#4'), ('computer', '#4')]

However, this assumes that, you will have single space, between `test` and `#1`. If you want to match multiple space, change the pattern to `\s+`.

Comment: I think you don't need to escape `<` and `>`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. haven't checked it, just did it for safety. Updated.

Comment: @N08, are you sure, in my test, it does.

Comment: Note it will also find a match with `computer (#4>`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OpVn5F/1). Note you do not need to escape any char inside the character classes :) (if you keep them at their current places).

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Is it possible to generalize the regex such that the bracket can be either the 1., 2. or 3. word after `test` or `computer` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes you are right, but IMO, escaping makes it more clear to comprehend, otherwise things like `[[]` looks pretty messy.

Comment: @N08, so rather than matching any number, you just want to much either `1`, `2` or `3`, right?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I would never write `[[]`, in that case, I would write `\[`.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque No, what I mean is that what if, say, two words were between the bracket `<...>` and `test` such as in this example: `"this is a test of <#1> that can be a very good test <#2>`. This would find `[["test", "#1"], ["test", "#2"]]`